# What is the minimum number of nodes for a private I2P testnet?

Tags: kovri, i2p, testnet

What is the minimum number of nodes for a private I2P testnet ?

Comment: Are you referring to Monero nodes, I2P nodes, or both?

Comment: Number of I2P nodes

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the absolute minimum, but I expect you should need ~10 nodes to have most operations function smoothly.

Comment: Still don't know the answer, kinda not trivial to quantify ;) The most basic functionality is a full roundtrip client-server-client. With 3 hops per tunnel (hard coded default), this requires 12 hops (different I2P nodes), so 14 nodes. In addition, 2 nodes can only communicate in a single direction. Destinations choose random nodes to build tunnels, the probability that these nodes that can communicate in the direction that the initiator desires (must not already have a transport session in the opposite direction) has to be non negligible ...